# robot_pose_ekf does not publish anything

Tags: ekf, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

~$ rostopic list

```
/cmd_vel
/control_vel
/encoder/odom
/imu/data
/imu_data
/md49_data
/md49_encoders
/pr2_base_odometry/odom
/ref_pose
/ref_vel
/robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
/tf_static
/vo
```

~$ rosnode info /robot_pose_ekf

```
Node [/robot_pose_ekf]
Publications: 
 * /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped]
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]
 * /tf [tf2_msgs/TFMessage]

Subscriptions: 
 * /imu_data [unknown type]
 * /pr2_base_odometry/odom [unknown type]
 * /tf [tf2_msgs/TFMessage]
 * /tf_static [unknown type]
 * /vo [unknown type]

Services: 
 * /robot_pose_ekf/get_loggers
 * /robot_pose_ekf/get_status
 * /robot_pose_ekf/set_logger_level


contacting node http://192.168.43.230:42337/ ...
Pid: 3826
Connections:
 * topic: /rosout
    * to: /rosout
    * direction: outbound (38899 - 192.168.43.230:42576) [13]
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /tf
    * to: /robot_pose_ekf
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: INTRAPROCESS
 * topic: /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined
    * to: /kin_controller_3834_1590954489145
    * direction: outbound (38899 - 192.168.43.230:42588) [10]
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined
    * to: /dyn_controller_3855_1590954494644
    * direction: outbound (38899 - 192.168.43.230:42600) [11]
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /tf
    * to: /robot_pose_ekf (http://192.168.43.230:42337/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: INTRAPROCESS
 * topic: /tf
    * to: /imu_to_base (http://192.168.43.204:39589/)
    * direction: inbound (51902 - 192.168.43.204:43869) [16]
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /tf
    * to: /imu/i2c_imu_node (http://192.168.43.204:44281/)
    * direction: inbound (37934 - 192.168.43.204:42235) [17]
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /tf
    * to: /base_odometry_node (http://192.168.43.230:43997/)
    * direction: inbound (53868 - 192.168.43.230:56183) [15]
    * transport: TCPROS
```

**There are no response for this command**

```
~$ rostopic echo /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined
```

**I want to echo the output of "robot_pose_ekf"**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353633/robot_pose_ekf-does-not-publish-anything/) by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-05-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2020-05-31**:
I had a similar issue the answer was to delete the "/" at the beginning of the topic name. rostopic echo robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined

**Comment by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on 2020-05-31**:
There are no response also

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2020-05-31**:
What does "rostopic hz ..." print? What does "rostopic info ..." print? "roswtf --all"?

**Comment by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on 2020-05-31**:
This the launch file of the robot pose ekf

```
<launch>
<node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">
  <param name="output_frame" value="odom_combined"/>
  <param name="base_footprint_frame" value="base_footprint"/>
  <param name="freq" value="30.0"/>
  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>  
  <param name="odom_used" value="true"/>
  <param name="imu_used" value="true"/>
  <param name="vo_used" value="true"/>
  <remap from="odom" to="pr2_base_odometry/odom" />
</node>
</launch>
```

**Comment by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on 2020-05-31**:
~$ rostopic hz /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined

```
subscribed to [/robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined]
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
```

**Comment by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on 2020-05-31**:
I have edited the post  and have showed the :

rosnode info /robot_pose_ekf

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2020-05-31**:
Does the tf work? rosrun tf view_frames - whats the output tree?

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2020-05-31**:
Are the odom imu and vo actually publishing? What do their rostopic info say?

**Comment by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on 2020-05-31**:
rosrun tf view_frames

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q6uNMweQiyzAyT2Naefa7H9jIXY01yNj/view?usp=sharing

**Comment by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on 2020-05-31**:
Are the odom imu and vo actually publishing?

```
    /encoder/odom
    /imu/data
    /imu_data               >>>>>>>> No output 
    /md49_data
    /md49_encoders
    /pr2_base_odometry/odom         >>>> No output 
    /ref_pose
    /ref_vel
    /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined      >>>>>>>> No output 
    /vo                                                      >>>>>>>> No output
```

**Comment by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on 2020-05-31**:
What do their rostopic info say?

~$ rosnode info /robot_pose_ekf

```
Node [/robot_pose_ekf]
Publications: 
 * /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped]
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]
 * /tf [tf2_msgs/TFMessage]

Subscriptions: 
 * /imu_data [unknown type]
 * /pr2_base_odometry/odom [unknown type]
 * /tf [tf2_msgs/TFMessage]
 * /tf_static [unknown type]
 * /vo [unknown type]

Services: 
 * /robot_pose_ekf/get_loggers
 * /robot_pose_ekf/get_status
 * /robot_pose_ekf/set_logger_level
```

the reminder of the  rostopic info in the main post.
I have edited the post and have showed the rostopic info, please take a look again to the main post

**Comment by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on 2020-05-31**:
Are the launch file as is showed above  is correct ?

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2020-05-31**:
Moved to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems you dont feed the node with input and thus it never starts "working". Also your tf tree will not work (there are actually two), make a static transform from base_footprint to base_link in the appropriate launchfile. [link text](https://answers.ros.org/question/208002/static-transformation-publisher/) Take a look at the link to get an idea of static transform if you dont know about it yet (x, y, z etc. you can make all zero, making base_footrpint equal to base_link, if you are using a wheeled robot base). In the end If you get odom imu and vo (do you really need vo?) publishing and the tf tree linked up, it should work.

---

Originally posted by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) with karma: 574 on 2020-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2020-05-31**:
By the way, for a launchfile try this:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">
  <param name="output_frame" value="odom_combined"/>
  <param name="base_footprint_frame" value="base_link"/>
  <param name="freq" value="30.0"/>
  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>  
  <param name="odom_used" value="true"/>
  <param name="imu_used" value="true"/>
  <param name="vo_used" value="false"/>
  <remap from="odom" to="encoder/odom" />
 <remap from="imu_data" to="imu/data" />
</node>
</launch>
```

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2020-05-31**:
Try this launchfile the above will not work as encoder/odom uses base_footprint frame:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="static_transform" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 0  /base_footprint /base_link  100"/>


<node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">
  <param name="output_frame" value="odom_combined"/>
  <param name="base_footprint_frame" value="base_footprint"/>
  <param name="freq" value="30.0"/>
  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>  
  <param name="odom_used" value="true"/>
  <param name="imu_used" value="true"/>
  <param name="vo_used" value="false"/>
  <remap from="odom" to="encoder/odom" />
 <remap from="imu_data" to="imu/data" />
</node>
</launch>
```

**Comment by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on 2020-05-31**:
I try to use the second launch file, and it gives this errors in the terminal window :

[link text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16M0smC3zvg0ljkFyJVjmO9I-o3q4llgS/view?usp=sharing)

and the rosnod info is

$ rosnode info /robot_pose_ekf

```
Node [/robot_pose_ekf]
Publications: 
 * /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped]
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]
 * /tf [tf2_msgs/TFMessage]

Subscriptions: 
 * /encoder/odom [nav_msgs/Odometry]
 * /imu/data [sensor_msgs/Imu]
 * /tf [tf2_msgs/TFMessage]
 * /tf_static [unknown type]
```

**and still there are no outputs foe robot_pose_ekf**

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2020-06-01**:
Sorry, the static transform publisher had a axis to many, try this:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="static_transform" args="0 0 0 0 0 0  /base_footprint /base_link  100"/>


<node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">
  <param name="output_frame" value="odom_combined"/>
  <param name="base_footprint_frame" value="base_footprint"/>
  <param name="freq" value="30.0"/>
  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>  
  <param name="odom_used" value="true"/>
  <param name="imu_used" value="true"/>
  <param name="vo_used" value="false"/>
  <remap from="odom" to="encoder/odom" />
 <remap from="imu_data" to="imu/data" />
</node>
</launch>
```

**Comment by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on 2020-06-01**:
[ERROR] [1591037796.233442009]: Covariance specified for measurement on topic wheelodom is zero

```
[ERROR] [1591037796.233741326]: filter time older than odom message buffer
[ERROR] [1591037796.233884657]: filter time older than odom message buffer
^C[ERROR] [1591037796.330767126]: filter time older than odom message buffer
[ERROR] [1591037796.331129977]: Covariance specified for measurement on topic wheelodom is zero
[ERROR] [1591037796.331370539]: filter time older than odom message buffer
[ERROR] [1591037796.333372238]: filter time older than odom message buffer
```

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2020-06-01**:
Never seen the topic wheelodom before in your posts whats that? The covariances have to fit of course but that has nothing to do with what this question is about. (for testing just make them tiny but non zero) The "filter time..." error is about unsynchronized topics, some data isnt coming in at all or not fast enough, as the timeout is 10 seconds, its likely not coming at all, most likely its the odometry problem causing this error as well. base_odometry_node is publishing odom on encoder/odom topic and the launchfile is remapping this.

**Comment by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on 2020-06-01**:
rostopic echo /encoder/odom

header:
seq: 33694
stamp:
secs: 1591041155
nsecs: 601311323
frame_id: "encoder/odom"
child_frame_id: "base_footprint"
pose:
pose:
position:
x: -316254.234024
y: 105513.04894
z: 0.0
orientation:
x: 0.0
y: 0.0
z: 0.697199495245
w: 0.716877160907
covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist:
twist:
linear:
x: 0.0986509230208
y: 0.0
z: 0.0
angular:
x: 0.0
y: 0.0
z: -0.0962888348611
covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2020-06-01**:
The covariances are zero here as well. If those get populated correctly it should all work. So the actual question seems solved. [link text](https://answers.ros.org/question/64759/covariance-matrix-for-vo-and-odom/) Link to a simple start to get into the covariance matrix topic.

**Comment by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on 2020-06-01**:
Thank you for you long long help.. I really appreciate that so much.
Where can i put this  covariance is a float[36] a 6x6 matrix?

```
[0.01  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0,
 0.0  0.01  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0,
 0.0   0.0 0.01  0.0  0.0  0.0,
 0.0   0.0  0.0  0.1  0.0  0.0,
 0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.1  0.0,
 0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.1]
```

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2020-06-01**:
Your welcome. Dont forget to mark the answer preceding this comments as answered, so people find the comments as well, if it all works finally. You should measure the accuracy of your odometry to get real data for the matrix. This is just an example matrix, but good enough to find out if robot_pose_ekf fires up after all. Iam very sure that this will work now. Populating the matrix is done in the node that calculates the odometry and publishes the message, in your case its in the base_odometry_node as your earlier postet tf tree shows.

**Comment by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on 2020-06-02**:
Thanks Dragonslayer' .

Really you have saved me.